# What is the difference between docker FROM and RUN apt-get?

Tags: docker

I see that some containers are created FROM official Apache docker image while some others are created from a Debian image with RUN apt get install. What is the difference? What is the best practice here and which one should I prefer?

Comment: There are no preferences. If it is in a repository why hesitate to not you use `FROM`? Some images may include different technologies and tools and predefined env variables and other configurations which you have to spend some time to install and configure if done manually. Also maintaining a docker image is much simpler than maintaining separate utilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really basic. The purpose of the two commands are different.

When you want to create an image of your own for your specific purpose you you go thru two steps:

1. Find a suitable base image to start from. And there is a lot of images out there. That is where you use the FROM clause... To get a starting point.
2. Specialize the image to a more specific purpose. And that is where your use RUN to install new things into the new image and often also COPY to add scripts and configurations to the new image.

So in your case: If you want to control the installation of Apache then you start of with a basic Debian image (FROM) and control the installation on Apache yourself (RUN). Or if you want to make it easy your find an image where Apache is alreay there, ready to run.